# How can I create a permission of file creation but no modification on a folder?

Tags: permissions

I have a SMB share where people can upload stuff, but I would like to set a permission like: "Write once, no changes allowed". So people do not mess each other files.

Found this [article](https://www.ostechnix.com/prevent-files-folders-accidental-deletion-modification-linux/) but it shows immutable attribute for files not folders.

It would be convenient having a permission like this, so to avoid creating a new user for each person, and files can be available to all users.

Is it anyhow possible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can set "sticky bit" on directory then only owner of files can delete them while the directory has world-writable permission.

Comment: This also restricts editing?

Comment: it depends on your `umask`, by default only user and it's group can have `rw` and others only `r`. you can set `umask` for your samba share

Comment: I don't think it is possible, because to create a file a user must have write permission.

Comment: a user must have write permission in directory. after creation of the file what should be it's permissions? (`umask` decides) so if perms are 664, others only can read it. to delete a file, need to have write permissions on it's parent directory, while having sticky bit and write, users only can delete their own files not others.